# Is this proof of with absolute values and inequalities correct?

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, absolute-value

Show,

$||a − c| − |b − d|| ≤ |a − b| + |c − d||$

To show this, we use the property of absolute values,

$|x|\le y$  iff $-y\le x\le y$

Applying this to our inequality gives,

$|b − a| + |d − c|≤|a − c| − |b − d| ≤ |a − b| + |c − d||$

For, $-y\le x$

Using the Absolute Value-Square Root Theorem,

$\sqrt{(b − a)^2} + \sqrt{(d − c)^2}≤\sqrt{(a − c)^2}− \sqrt{(b − d)^2}$

Squaring both sides,

$ {a^2}+{b^2}+{c^2}+{d^2}-2ab-2cd+2bd-2bc-2ad+2ac ≤{a^2}+{b^2}+{c^2}+{d^2}-2ab+2cd+2bd+2bc-2ad-2ac$

Simplifying leaves us,

$ -(d-a+b)≤(d-a+b)$

So, we have shown $-y\le x$ for any a,b,c and d.

For $x\le y$. We do the same thing: use the above mentioned theorem, square and simplify. However, this leaves $0=0$. Does this prove $x\le y$ ?

I'm still learning proofs so I apologize if this is elementary stuff. Is this enough to prove my statement? It seems like it might not communicate what I want to show although I'm fairly sure I'm close

Comment: It is *much* simpler if you know the triangle inequalities: $||x|-|y|| \le |x+y| \le |x| + |y|$.

Comment: How did you get the expression after “squaring both sides”? That looks wrong. – And why do you think that $-(d-a+b)≤(d-a+b)$ is true? What if $d+a-b$ is negative?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so this does not prove the statement at all. I'm going to try using the triangle inequality. I'm a bit unsure of how to apply it but I'll try

Comment: $|x|+|y|\geq|x\pm y|\geq||x|-|y||$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your proof:

- Squaring both sides of an inequality is produces an equivalent inequality *only* if both sides are known to be non-negative. That is not the case here, the right-hand side $\sqrt{(a − c)^2}− \sqrt{(b − d)^2}$ can be negative.
- Squaring both sides of the inequality is done incorrectly.
- Your final inequality $-(d-a+b) \le (d-a+b)$ need not be true. So even if all previous steps were correct (which they are not), this would not prove the desired estimate.

Note that it  much is easier to use the triangle inequalities $||x|-|y|| \le |x \pm y| \le |x| + |y|$:

$$
||a − c| − |b − d||   \le |(a-c) - (b-d)|
= |(a-b) - (c-d)| \le |a − b| + |c − d| \, .
$$

Comment: I figured out how to do it this way too and it is much easier, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right.

After squaring of the both sides we need to prove that:
$$|(a-c)(b-d)|+|(a-b)(c-d)|\geq ab+cd-ac-bd$$ or
$$|ab+cd-ad-bc|+|ad+bc-ac-bd|\geq ab+cd-ac-bd,$$ which is true by the triangle inequality:
$$|ab+cd-ad-bc|+|ad+bc-ac-bd|\geq |ab+cd-ac-bd|\geq ab+cd-ac-bd.$$

Comment: I think I'm squaring incorrectly. I believe I'm supposed to get absolute values on one side like stated here

Comment: @John MacPherson But your idea is very good.